# Run time compile order

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm coding in Javascript and I came to an example which I figure was strange.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(95,50,20,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

The above example works and outputs a circle.

However, when I try to copy the exact codes of the script onto a javascript.js file, the circle ceases to exist. Why is that the case?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="javascriptFile.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

I thought the order of precedence would be that the web browser publishes the html code, and then constructs the DOM which I figure javascript code would run right after the html objects are created. I tried putting a function createShape() inside the canvas and then insert the rest of the codes in function createShape(){} of the javascriptFile.js file but didn't work either.

Would I have to always put the javascript codes in the html body for all canvas objects?

Comment: Make sure your script tag is below the canvas element, better yet, do the stuff after the document has been loaded (window.onload etc)

Comment: The canvas doesn't exist yet when the script runs.

Comment: thats why we need document ready state... to know everything needed loaded :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought the order of precedence would be that the web browser publishes the html code, and then constructs the DOM which I figure javascript code would run right after the html objects are created.

That is incorrect. Generally, if your JavaScript code appears in the source before the elements it is trying to access (and is not explicitly [marked as `defer`ed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes)), it will be [executed before the browser continues to parse the page.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Embed the script at the bottom of the body and you should be fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script src="javascriptFile.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! So I guess I should always place my javascriptFile.js at the bottom of the code then? Just a line above the /body tag

Comment: Either that, or execute your code after the `window.onload` event has been fired, which indicates that the page has been rendered completely.

Comment: Oh I see, that's fairly interesting. I still don't quite understand the concept of window.onload yet. Do I implement this on the html body tag?

Comment: Check out [the MDN page on `window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload).

Comment: Thanks again @Timo!! Hopefully I'll be able to sort things out with all of this, as of now everything as you suggested works! :)